# SIGKILL instead of NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification in iOS 8.1 iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

There are related questions on SO, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20284535/27779), and while this issue is mentioned, it is not the crux of that question or any of the others I could find.

I have written an iOS 8.1 application called Cloudy, which is just a test bed for learning Core Data for iCloud. The documentation says that to detect a change in iCloud account status, one should listen for `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` and then examine the value of `NSFileManager`'s `ubiquityIdentityToken` property. Conceptually, this is very simple and straightforward. The problem is that it never happens.

Instead, my application always receives `SIGKILL` when I sign out of iCloud or disable iCloud Documents. In some of the comments to the linked SO question above, some guessed that this occurs only when debugging through Xcode, but I can assure you this is not the case. It also occurs when simply launching the app without a debugger connected.

Now, `SIGKILL` is just fine. In fact, it makes my life easier. The problem is that I cannot find this behavior documented anywhere, so I don't trust it. However, since I have never been able to capture `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification`, it is impossible to test any code written to handle it.

While iCloud is a great technology, the documentation for it is maybe half a notch above terrible.

Comment: I have suspicion that this is related to testing in XCode. Are you getting the same if you test on real device ?

Comment: I started to get this behaviour when I switched my app from iOS7 to 8.  I have also tried on my phone debugging from Xcode, and it fails with the same SIGKILL.

Comment: Did some more digging around and testing on this.  When a user logs out of a privileged service such as iCloud, a SIGKILL will be sent.  This is the expected behaviour.  On the device, the app is killed, and then restarted.  I guess the thinking is that the heavy hammer is better in this case, as the app will determine if someone is logged in/out on startup.  However, when you log into iCloud, no SIGKILL is sent - so you still need to use the Notification Center to get this change as per the Apple documentation.  So the logout/login behaviour is asymetric