# How to know Calendar's Syncing is Off in iCloud Settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, eventkit

Is there any way to know programatically that in `iPhone Settings` -> `iCloud` -> `Calendars` is switched off/on? Because in both case app is getting the iCloud in `EKSource` object.

```
    // Get the calendar source
EKSource* currentSource;
for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources)
{
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV &&
        [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"])
    {/*True in two cases
      1. if iCloud Signed In and Calendars switch is On
      2. if iCloud Signed In but Calendars switch is Off*/

        currentSource = source;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this?

Comment: also looking for this answer. this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284535/ talks about checking iCloud off/on but not specifically calendar

Comment: I'd also like to know.