# ios icloud set on/off programatically in the device

Tags: ios, device, icloud, isenabled

Im new with iOS and ICloud. I have an app that syncs core data with iCloud, and i want to know how can i check if the device has the iCloud or iCloud Drive setting disabled, and in that case ask the user to enable it programatically from the app.

Example:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296718/927766) this is already answered

Answer (score 1):

`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` can be used to check whether the current user’s iCloud account can be accessed.

> This method determines the status of the current user’s iCloud account
>   asynchronously, reporting the results to the block in the
>   completionHandler parameter.

It is available in ios 8 and later.